# Admins loggin in to our wordpress site default to the admin page

Tags: admin, login

Each time an admin logs in to our regular site (NOT wp-admin), they end up on the dashboard page, not the site home page. In other words, browsing to www.mysite.com and then logging in should bring me to my home page, but instead, it brings me to the dashboard, as if I'd accessed www.mysite.com/wp-admin. How is this forced?

Answer (score 0):

if user try to login directly by `example.com/wp-login.php` without `redirect_to` parameter after authentication [`wp-login.php` check the user's capability](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-login.php#L830) and decide where to redirect the user.

you can modify this behavior with [`login_redirect`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-login.php#L812) filter hook.